# Angular service field is undefined for one controller only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, controllers, angular-services

I have defined a simple service:

```
app.service('AuthenticationService', function() {
  var auth = {
    isLogged: false
  };
  return auth;
});
```

I use this to set and share the authentication state between controllers. It reads fine in my LoginCtrl:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
  function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService) {

    $scope.login = function logIn(username, password) {
      if (username !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
        UserService.login(username, password)
        .success(function(data) {
          AuthenticationService.isLogged = true; //sets value correctly
          $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
          $location.path("/main");
        })
        .error(function(status, data) {
          console.log(status);
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    };

    //...

}]);
```

As it does in MainCtrl:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
      function MainCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService) {

      //...

      $scope.logout = function() {
        console.log("LOGOUT CALLED AT MAIN CONTROLLER. isLogged "
 + AuthenticationService.isLogged); //prints true
        if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
          AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
          delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
          $location.path("/");
        }
      };

    }]);
```

However it is inaccessible from this controller, even though I'm pretty sure I'm injecting the service correctly:

```
    app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'MovieDataService', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
      function SearchCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService, MovieDataService) {

    //...

      $scope.logout = function() {
        console.log("LOGOUT CALLED AT SEARCH CONTROLLER. isLogged: "
 + AuthenticationService.isLogged); //prints undefined
        if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
          //UserService.logout();
          AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
          delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
          $location.path("/");
        }
      };
    //...
    }]);
```

Why is this happening? I'm not unsetting isLogged anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'MovieDataService', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
  function SearchCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService, MovieDataService) {
```

should be

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'MovieDataService', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
  function SearchCtrl($scope, $location, $window, MovieDataService, UserService, AuthenticationService) {
```

In other words, you need to make sure the order of arguments in your function matches the preceding list of argument names/dependencies.

To quote the [AngularJS DI documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) (emphasis mine):

> ### Inline Array Annotation
>
> This is the preferred way to annotate application components. This is
>   how the examples in the documentation are written.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
>   // ...
> }]);
> ```
>
> Here we pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings (the
>   names of the dependencies) followed by the function itself.
>
> When using this type of annotation, **take care to keep the annotation
>   array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration**.

Comment: Wow. Coding while sleepy is NOT productive. Even so I did not know the order mattered. Thank you very much, you saved me hours of aimlessly debugging

Answer (score 0):

your injection order is wrong 
is should be

```
['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'MovieDataService', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', 
      function SearchCtrl($scope, $location, $window, MovieDataService, UserService, AuthenticationService){}]
```

the name of service and service passed in should be same order

Comment: @tavnab yes you are, i was typing my answer when there is no answers